# Mixed distribution problem where $F(x) = aF_d(x) + (1-a)F_c(x)$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let $F(x) = aF_d(x) + (1-a)F_c(x)$ be the CDF of a mixed type, where

> $F(x) = $ $\begin{cases} 0,    \; \;x<0,\\ {(x+1)\over 8} \;\    0\le x < 5, \\ 1, \ x\ge 5, \end{cases}$

$F_d(x)$ and $F_c(x)$ are the CDFs of discrete and continuous type, respectively.

a) Give either the discrete CDF $F_d(x)$ or the discrete pdf $f_d(x).$

b) Calculate $E(X)$, where $X$ has the $F(x)$ given above.

I absolutely do not get mixed distributions.  I don't know how to calculate them.  Can anyone help me?

Comment: First thing to search for are step discontinuities in the CDF, as found in discrete distributions  Oh, there they are at $x=0$ and $x=5$. $$F(0^-)=0, F(0^+)=0+\tfrac 18\\ F(5^-)=\tfrac 68, F(5^+)=\tfrac 68+\tfrac 28$$  What does that tell you about the discrete component? What about the coefficient $a$?

Comment: Ok a is the sum of jumps so $a = {1\over 8} + {1\over 4} = {3 \over 8}$

Comment: @GrahamKemp  How would you construct the pdf of $f_d(x)$ then?

Comment: Well, *you* just said $a\,f_d(0)=\tfrac 18$ and $a\,f_d(5)=\tfrac 28$ so.... (BTW, that means $a=\tfrac 83$)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing to search for are step discontinuities in the CDF, as found in discrete distributions  Oh, there they are at $x=0$ and $x=5$. $$F(0^-)=0, F(0^+)=0+\tfrac 18\\ F(5^-)=\tfrac 68, F(5^+)=\tfrac 68+\tfrac 28$$  What does that tell you about the discrete component? What about the coefficient $a$?

> $$a\,f_d(x) =\begin{cases} 1/8 &:& x=0\\ 2/8 &:& x=5\\0&:&\text{elsewhere}\end{cases}$$ 
>
> So...

Comment: uh when x=0 the $f_d(x) = 1/3$ and when x = 2 $f_d(x) = 2/3$  where did 1/3 and 2/3 come from?  That's my professor's answer

Comment: @NTT Because $a f_d(0)+a f_d(5)=3/8$ when $f_d(0)+f_d(5)=1$, so therefore to what equals $a$?  So thus if $a\,f_d(0)=1/8$, then to what equals $f_d(0)$? $f_d(5)$ also.

Comment: I think I got it! Thanks!  If they ask me to find the continuous pdf I might be screw lol